# dynamixel_workbench_controller does not publish joint states during motion

Tags: ros, joint-state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the dynamixel_workbench_controller to control a single MX-28. It works great, joint states are published and I can move it using the joint_operator.

however, during the execution of the motion, the published joint_states (if they are published at all during the motion) do not change. which is very sad....

Does anyone have a hint?

Best,

Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390698/dynamixel_workbench_controller-does-not-publish-joint-states-during-motion/) by [georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/89395/georg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not a bug, it is a feature! Actually I just found out, that the generation of joint state msgs is suppressed during motion. I found some discussion on the internet, that someone obviously had issues with the bandwidth over the serial connection and the developer at ROBOTIS chose to suppress the messages during runtime. Since the source code is available on github, I could revert the change and did not yet find any issues.

---

Originally posted by [georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/89395/georg/) with karma: 11 on 2021-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-12**:
Thank you for sharing your answer. You can accept your answer by clicking the check mark.